# pytest.raises(AssertionError) fails with cython modules

Tags: cython, pytest

Define the files python_assert.py and cython_assert.pyx to be identical, each containing a simple function that raises AssertionError:

```
def raise_assertionerror():
    assert False
```

I would expect both of the following tests to succeed under pytest:

```
import pytest

import pyximport
pyximport.install()

from python_assert import raise_assertionerror as python_assert
from cython_assert import raise_assertionerror as cython_assert

def test_assertion():
    with pytest.raises(AssertionError):
        python_assert()

def test_cython_assertion():
    with pytest.raises(AssertionError):
        cython_assert()
```

However, the cython test fails:

```
===================================== FAILURES ======================================
_______________________________ test_cython_assertion _______________________________

    def test_cython_assertion():
        with pytest.raises(AssertionError):
>           cython_assert()

test_pytest_assertion.py:15: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

>   assert False
E   AssertionError

cython_assert.pyx:2: AssertionError
======================== 1 failed, 1 passed in 0.61 seconds =========================
```

This seems to be a problem with pytest because the equivalent unittest succeeds:

```
import unittest

import pyximport
pyximport.install()

from python_assert import raise_assertionerror as python_assert
from cython_assert import raise_assertionerror as cython_assert

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_cython(self):
        self.assertRaises(AssertionError, cython_assert)

    def test_python(self):
        self.assertRaises(AssertionError, python_assert)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Further, the pytest test succeeds if we call `pytest.raises(Exception)` instead of `pytest.raises(AssertionError)`.

Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been [recognized as a bug in pytest](https://bitbucket.org/hpk42/pytest/issue/176/pytestraises-assertionerror-fails-with) and resolved.